# Count data Using codeigniter monthly wise

Tags: codeigniter, sqlsrv

I am using Codeigniter 3.0 and sql Server

This is my table

```
customers table:
Amount      Date                            Id
1.00      2014-01-05 00:00:00.000           1
2.00      2014-01-11 00:00:00.000           1
3.00      2014-02-03 00:00:00.000           1
2.00      2014-02-05 00:00:00.000           1
```

And I want to display my output as

```
January 3.00
February 5.00
!!!!!!

December 12.00
```

So, how can i count that Amount and how to put all days to a single month

and i am using codeigniter 3.0, my database is sql server 2012

```
public function overviews(){
 //   $merchantid=$this->session->userdata('user_password');
   $baji=$this->livemerchant_model->overviews();
    $name=$this->session->userdata('name');
           $data=array('baji'=>$baji,'name'=>$name);

   if($this->session->has_userdata('user_email','name')){
    $this->load->view('overviews.php', $data);


     }
   }
```

sfnerd this is my controller and is it possible to display data like

```
select year 
january  12.00
february 24.00


Total    36.00
```

and i want display count of amount for selected year only

```
<label class="tp-label">Select a year</label>
                                                              <select>
                                                               <?php
foreach($monthlyTotals as $row)
{
?>
<option value = "<?php echo $row->TheYear?>"><?php echo $row->TheYear;?>    </option>
<?php
}
?>
```

so when i did this loop i am getting years repeatedly based on months like 2014 12 times, and i need the output like select year 2015 and i have load button when i click on that button needs to display 12 months

```
public function overviews()
{
$this->load->model('livemerchant_model');
$name=$this->session->userdata('name');
$data['monthlyTotals'] = $this->livemerchant_model-  >overviews($theyear='');
$this->load->view('overviews', $data);
}
```

And used this controller

Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely a few ways to do this, but here are two way to do it (one using Active Record, one straight SQL). I tested with CI 3.0.6 and SQL Server 2012 and created a similar table.

**MODEL FUNCTION** (assume model is called Customers)

***Straight SQL Version:***

```
function get_monthly_totals($theYear = '', $theMonth = '')
{
    $sql = "SELECT DATEPART(Year, Date) [TheYear], DATEPART(Month, Date) [TheMonth], DATENAME(Month, Date) [TheMonthName], SUM(Amount) [TotalAmount]
        FROM Customers
        WHERE Date IS NOT NULL ";

    if ($theYear != '') {
        $sql = $sql . " AND DATEPART(Year, Date) = '$theYear'";
    }

    if ($theMonth != '') {
        $sql = $sql . " AND DATEPART(Month, Date) = '$theMonth'";
    }

    $sql = $sql . " GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, Date), DATEPART(Month, Date), DATENAME(Month, Date) ORDER BY [TheYear], [TheMonth], [TheMonthName]";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->result();
}
```

***Active Record version:***

```
function get_monthly_totals($theYear = '', $theMonth = '')
{

    $this->db->select("DATEPART(Year, Date) [TheYear], DATEPART(Month, Date) [TheMonth], DATENAME(Month, Date) [TheMonthName], SUM(Amount) [TotalAmount]", false);
    $this->db->from('Customers');

    if ($theYear != '') {
        $this->db->where("DATEPART(Year, Date) = '" . $theYear . "'", NULL, FALSE);
    }

    if ($theMonth != '') {
        $this->db->where("DATEPART(Month, Date) = '" . $theMonth . "'", NULL, FALSE);
    }

    $this->db->group_by("DATEPART(Year, Date), DATEPART(Month, Date), DATENAME(Month, Date)");
    $this->db->order_by("1", "asc");
    $this->db->order_by("2", "asc");
    $this->db->order_by("3", "asc");

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

---

**CONTROLLER FUNCTION**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Customers_model');

    $data['monthlyTotals'] = $this->Customers_model->get_monthly_totals('2014');

    $this->load->view('customers', $data);
}
```

**VIEW OUTPUT** (customers.php)

```
<?php 
    foreach ($monthlyTotals as $row)
    {
        echo $row->TheYear . " - " . $row->TheMonthName . ": " . $row->TotalAmount . " <br />" . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks cfnerd its working for me ........ but i am getting all years records but i want year selection like select year and display 12 months records

Comment: @shaik you can adjust the query in the controller to do that by adding a WHERE clause.  The WHERE could be something you pass in via variable, or something that is static.

Comment: Thnak you @cfnerd .. Actually I have edited my question could you please check and give me a solution

Comment: @shaik I have updated the answer.  I tested this way, and it works well.  You can now pass variables into the model function.  I also put an example of how to do this using the Active Record functionality in CI.

Comment: And a small query can we pass year variable dynamically, becauese i want to select year as dropdown in my view file when i select 2014 or 2015 or any year i want to get that year's months total

Comment: @shaik, yes you can pass a variable into the function rather than a static date.  That variable can come from a form dropdown.

Comment: i have added some view file code and controller could please check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622392/display-result-by-selecting-option-in-codeigniter-3-0?noredirect=1#comment60841299_36622392 @cfnerd could you help for my question to the link which i added here

Answer (score 0):

In my case i did following code

```
public function earning_chart_year($DriverId,$year){
    $this->db->select_sum('driverCommision');
    $this->db->select('MONTHNAME(displayTime) as createDate');        
    $this->db->group_by('monthname(displayTime)');
    $this->db->where('driverId',$DriverId);
    $this->db->where('year(displayTime)',$year);
    $result=$this->db->get('BookingMaster')->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Output :

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [totalBooking] => 52
>               [createDate] => November
>           )

)