# Display result by selecting option in codeigniter 3.0

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjULN.png)
Actually when i select merchant id and year i want to display result, but how to use that select button can any one help me resolve the issue

This is my model

```
function overviews($theYear = '', $theMonth = '')
{

$this->db->select("DATEPART(Year, TRANS_TransactionDate) [TheYear], DATEPART(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate) [TheMonth], DATENAME(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate) [TheMonthName], SUM(TRANS_Amount) [TotalAmount]", false);
$this->db->from('BTBL_Transactions');

if ($theYear != '') {
    $this->db->where("DATEPART(Year, TRANS_TransactionDate) = '" . $theYear . "'", NULL, FALSE);
}

if ($theMonth != '') {
    $this->db->where("DATEPART(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate) = '" .  $theMonth . "'", NULL, FALSE);
}

$this->db->group_by("DATEPART(Year, TRANS_TransactionDate),   DATEPART(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate), DATENAME(Month,   TRANS_TransactionDate)");
$this->db->order_by("1", "asc");
$this->db->order_by("2", "asc");
$this->db->order_by("3", "asc");

$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result();
}

public function merchant_type_dropdown(){
$this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('TRANS_MerchantId');
    $this->db->from('BTBL_Transactions');
   $query= $this->db->get();
  // echo $this->db->last_query();die();
   if($query->num_rows()>0){
                       $result=$query->result();
                       return $result;

    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}

public function Year_dropdown(){
$this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('DATEPART(Year, TRANS_TransactionDate) [TheYear]');
    $this->db->from('BTBL_Transactions');
   $query= $this->db->get();
  // echo $this->db->last_query();die();
   if($query->num_rows()>0){
                       $result=$query->result();
                       return $result;

    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

And This is my Controller

```
 public function overviews()
{
$this->load->model('livemerchant_model');
$name=$this->session->userdata('name');
$data['monthlyTotals'] = $this->livemerchant_model- >overviews($theyear='');
$this->load->view('overviews', $data);
}
```

This is my view file

```
<label class="tp-label">Select a year</label>
                                                              <select>
                                                              <?php $year=$this->livemerchant_model->Year_dropdown(); 

                          foreach ($year as $row){
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row->TheYear ?>"><?php echo $row->TheYear ?></option>
                         <!--- <option value="tier_two">MPOS</option>
                          <option value="tier_three">E-Commerce</option>
                          <option value="tier_four">Virtual Machine</option>--->
                          <?php }?>
                                                              </select>
```

Merchant ID

```
                                                                 <?php $merchanttype=$this->livemerchant_model->merchant_type_dropdown(); 

                          foreach ($merchanttype as $merchant){
                          ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $merchant->TRANS_MerchantId ?>"><?php echo $merchant->TRANS_MerchantId ?></option>
                         <!--- <option value="tier_two">MPOS</option>
                          <option value="tier_three">E-Commerce</option>
                          <option value="tier_four">Virtual Machine</option>--->
                          <?php }?>
```

Comment: Pass the merchant id and year into the controller functions and use it to filter the resultant rows in model function using a where clause. To pass the values, you can either use a form submit or a javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand this correctly, but here is what I *think* you want to do.  First, you will need to adjust your Model function to accept another optional parameter.

```
function overviews($theMerchant = '', $theYear = '', $theMonth = '')
{
    $this->db->select("DATEPART(Year, TRANS_TransactionDate) [TheYear], DATEPART(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate) [TheMonth], DATENAME(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate) [TheMonthName], SUM(TRANS_Amount) [TotalAmount]", false);
    $this->db->from('BTBL_Transactions');

    if ($theYear != '') {
        $this->db->where("DATEPART(Year, TRANS_TransactionDate) = '" . $theYear . "'", NULL, FALSE);
    }

    if ($theMonth != '') {
        $this->db->where("DATEPART(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate) = '" .  $theMonth . "'", NULL, FALSE);
    }

    if ($theMerchant != '') {
        $this->db->where("TRANS_MerchantId", $theMerchant);
    }

    $this->db->group_by("DATEPART(Year, TRANS_TransactionDate),   DATEPART(Month, TRANS_TransactionDate), DATENAME(Month,   TRANS_TransactionDate)");
    $this->db->order_by("1", "asc");
    $this->db->order_by("2", "asc");
    $this->db->order_by("3", "asc");

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Once you do that, you are going to have to give the select boxes in your view a name attribute (and ideally an ID attribute).  Examples:

```
<select name="transactionYear" id="transactionYear" aria-required="true" required="required">
```

and...

```
<select name="transactionMerchant" id="transactionMerchant" aria-required="true" required="required">
```

Once you do that, you can adjust your controller like below.  In that, I am also showing you that it is likely better to pass your data into the view, rather than have your variables populated within the view:

```
public function overviews()
{
    $this->load->model('livemerchant_model');

    $name=$this->session->userdata('name');

    if ($this->input->post('transactionMerchant')) {
        $data['monthlyTotals'] = $this->livemerchant_model->overviews($this->input->post('transactionMerchant'), $this->input->post('transactionYear'));
    } else {
        $data['monthlyTotals'] = $this->livemerchant_model->overviews();
    }

    $data['merchanttype'] = $this->livemerchant_model->merchant_type_dropdown();
    $data['year'] = $this->livemerchant_model->Year_dropdown();

    $this->load->view('overviews', $data);
}
```

This should give you what you want.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @cfnerd for your response, Basicly i am new to codeigniter but when i subit after selecting id and result no luck, because my view page is in tabbing